# Problems with openvpn on ubuntu 22.04

Tags: ubuntu, openvpn

I'm trying to set up openvpn on the server using this guide:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-and-configure-an-openvpn-server-on-ubuntu-22-04

I got to step 10, but I can't start the openvpn service:

```
serv_ivan@964889-cd87180:~$ sudo systemctl -f enable openvpn-server@server.service
[sudo] password for serv_ivan: 
serv_ivan@964889-cd87180:~$ sudo systemctl start openvpn-server@server.service
serv_ivan@964889-cd87180:~$ sudo systemctl status openvpn-server@server.service
● openvpn-server@server.service - OpenVPN service for server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/openvpn-server@.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2022-08-01 21:33:03 MSK; 3s ago
       Docs: man:openvpn(8)
             https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/Openvpn24ManPage
             https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/HOWTO
    Process: 1256469 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/openvpn --status /run/openvpn-server/status-server.log --status-version 2 --suppress-timestamps --config server.conf (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 1256469 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
     Status: "Pre-connection initialization successful"
        CPU: 24ms

Aug 01 21:33:03 964889-cd87180.tmweb.ru systemd[1]: openvpn-server@server.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Aug 01 21:33:03 964889-cd87180.tmweb.ru systemd[1]: openvpn-server@server.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
serv_ivan@964889-cd87180:~$
```

I searched the Internet for an answer, but did not find it.

log:

```
serv_ivan@964889-cd87180:~$ sudo tail -n 20 /var/log/syslog
Aug  1 21:36:47 964889-cd87180 systemd[1]: Stopped OpenVPN connection to server.
Aug  1 21:36:47 964889-cd87180 systemd[1]: Starting OpenVPN connection to server...
Aug  1 21:36:47 964889-cd87180 ovpn-server[1257478]: Options error: In [CMD-LINE]:1: Error opening configuration file: /etc/openvpn/server.conf
Aug  1 21:36:47 964889-cd87180 ovpn-server[1257478]: Use --help for more information.
Aug  1 21:36:47 964889-cd87180 systemd[1]: openvpn@server.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Aug  1 21:36:47 964889-cd87180 systemd[1]: openvpn@server.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Aug  1 21:36:47 964889-cd87180 systemd[1]: Failed to start OpenVPN connection to server.
Aug  1 21:36:48 964889-cd87180 systemd[1]: openvpn-server@server.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 1733.
Aug  1 21:36:48 964889-cd87180 systemd[1]: Stopped OpenVPN service for server.
Aug  1 21:36:48 964889-cd87180 systemd[1]: Starting OpenVPN service for server...
Aug  1 21:36:48 964889-cd87180 systemd[1]: Started OpenVPN service for server.
Aug  1 21:36:48 964889-cd87180 networkd-dispatcher[1030209]: WARNING:Unknown index 49326 seen, reloading interface list
Aug  1 21:36:48 964889-cd87180 systemd-networkd[1214783]: tun1: Link UP
Aug  1 21:36:48 964889-cd87180 systemd-networkd[1214783]: tun1: Gained carrier
Aug  1 21:36:48 964889-cd87180 systemd-networkd[1214783]: tun1: Gained IPv6LL
Aug  1 21:36:48 964889-cd87180 systemd-udevd[1257483]: Using default interface naming scheme 'v249'.
Aug  1 21:36:48 964889-cd87180 systemd-networkd[1214783]: tun1: Link DOWN
Aug  1 21:36:48 964889-cd87180 systemd-networkd[1214783]: tun1: Lost carrier
Aug  1 21:36:48 964889-cd87180 systemd[1]: openvpn-server@server.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Aug  1 21:36:48 964889-cd87180 systemd[1]: openvpn-server@server.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
serv_ivan@964889-cd87180:~$
```

cat server.config:

```
#################################################
# Sample OpenVPN 2.0 config file for            #
# multi-client server.                          #
#                                               #
# This file is for the server side              #
# of a many-clients <-> one-server              #
# OpenVPN configuration.                        #
#                                               #
# OpenVPN also supports                         #
# single-machine <-> single-machine             #
# configurations (See the Examples page         #
# on the web site for more info).               #
#                                               #
# This config should work on Windows            #
# or Linux/BSD systems.  Remember on            #
# Windows to quote pathnames and use            #
# double backslashes, e.g.:                     #
# "C:\\Program Files\\OpenVPN\\config\\foo.key" #
#                                               #
# Comments are preceded with '#' or ';'         #
#################################################

# Which local IP address should OpenVPN
# listen on? (optional)
;local 94.228.120.106

# Which TCP/UDP port should OpenVPN listen on?
# If you want to run multiple OpenVPN instances
# on the same machine, use a different port
# number for each one.  You will need to
# open up this port on your firewall.
port 1194

# TCP or UDP server?
;proto tcp
proto udp

# "dev tun" will create a routed IP tunnel,
# "dev tap" will create an ethernet tunnel.
# Use "dev tap0" if you are ethernet bridging
# and have precreated a tap0 virtual interface
# and bridged it with your ethernet interface.
# If you want to control access policies
# over the VPN, you must create firewall
# rules for the the TUN/TAP interface.
# On non-Windows systems, you can give
# an explicit unit number, such as tun0.
# On Windows, use "dev-node" for this.
# On most systems, the VPN will not function
# unless you partially or fully disable
# the firewall for the TUN/TAP interface.
;dev tap
dev tun

# Windows needs the TAP-Win32 adapter name
# from the Network Connections panel if you
# have more than one.  On XP SP2 or higher,
# you may need to selectively disable the
# Windows firewall for the TAP adapter.
# Non-Windows systems usually don't need this.
;dev-node MyTap

# SSL/TLS root certificate (ca), certificate
# (cert), and private key (key).  Each client
# and the server must have their own cert and
# key file.  The server and all clients will
# use the same ca file.
#
# See the "easy-rsa" directory for a series
# of scripts for generating RSA certificates
# and private keys.  Remember to use
# a unique Common Name for the server
# and each of the client certificates.
#
# Any X509 key management system can be used.
# OpenVPN can also use a PKCS #12 formatted key file
# (see "pkcs12" directive in man page).
ca ca.crt
cert server.crt
key server.key  # This file should be kept secret

# Diffie hellman parameters.
# Generate your own with:
#   openssl dhparam -out dh2048.pem 2048
;dh dh2048.pem
dh none

# Network topology
# Should be subnet (addressing via IP)
# unless Windows clients v2.0.9 and lower have to
# be supported (then net30, i.e. a /30 per client)
# Defaults to net30 (not recommended)
;topology subnet

# Configure server mode and supply a VPN subnet
# for OpenVPN to draw client addresses from.
# The server will take 10.8.0.1 for itself,
# the rest will be made available to clients.
# Each client will be able to reach the server
# on 10.8.0.1. Comment this line out if you are
# ethernet bridging. See the man page for more info.
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0

# Maintain a record of client <-> virtual IP address
# associations in this file.  If OpenVPN goes down or
# is restarted, reconnecting clients can be assigned
# the same virtual IP address from the pool that was
# previously assigned.
ifconfig-pool-persist /var/log/openvpn/ipp.txt

# Configure server mode for ethernet bridging.
# You must first use your OS's bridging capability
# to bridge the TAP interface with the ethernet
# NIC interface.  Then you must manually set the
# IP/netmask on the bridge interface, here we
# assume 10.8.0.4/255.255.255.0.  Finally we
# must set aside an IP range in this subnet
# (start=10.8.0.50 end=10.8.0.100) to allocate
# to connecting clients.  Leave this line commented
# out unless you are ethernet bridging.
;server-bridge 10.8.0.4 255.255.255.0 10.8.0.50 10.8.0.100

# Configure server mode for ethernet bridging
# using a DHCP-proxy, where clients talk
# to the OpenVPN server-side DHCP server
# to receive their IP address allocation
# and DNS server addresses.  You must first use
# your OS's bridging capability to bridge the TAP
# interface with the ethernet NIC interface.
# Note: this mode only works on clients (such as
# Windows), where the client-side TAP adapter is
# bound to a DHCP client.
;server-bridge

# Push routes to the client to allow it
# to reach other private subnets behind
# the server.  Remember that these
# private subnets will also need
# to know to route the OpenVPN client
# address pool (10.8.0.0/255.255.255.0)
# back to the OpenVPN server.
;push "route 192.168.10.0 255.255.255.0"
;push "route 192.168.20.0 255.255.255.0"

# To assign specific IP addresses to specific
# clients or if a connecting client has a private
# subnet behind it that should also have VPN access,
# use the subdirectory "ccd" for client-specific
# configuration files (see man page for more info).

# EXAMPLE: Suppose the client
# having the certificate common name "Thelonious"
# also has a small subnet behind his connecting
# machine, such as 192.168.40.128/255.255.255.248.
# First, uncomment out these lines:
;client-config-dir ccd
;route 192.168.40.128 255.255.255.248
# Then create a file ccd/Thelonious with this line:
#   iroute 192.168.40.128 255.255.255.248
# This will allow Thelonious' private subnet to
# access the VPN.  This example will only work
# if you are routing, not bridging, i.e. you are
# using "dev tun" and "server" directives.

# EXAMPLE: Suppose you want to give
# Thelonious a fixed VPN IP address of 10.9.0.1.
# First uncomment out these lines:
;client-config-dir ccd
;route 10.9.0.0 255.255.255.252
# Then add this line to ccd/Thelonious:
#   ifconfig-push 10.9.0.1 10.9.0.2

# Suppose that you want to enable different
# firewall access policies for different groups
# of clients.  There are two methods:
# (1) Run multiple OpenVPN daemons, one for each
#     group, and firewall the TUN/TAP interface
#     for each group/daemon appropriately.
# (2) (Advanced) Create a script to dynamically
#     modify the firewall in response to access
#     from different clients.  See man
#     page for more info on learn-address script.
;learn-address ./script

# If enabled, this directive will configure
# all clients to redirect their default
# network gateway through the VPN, causing
# all IP traffic such as web browsing and
# and DNS lookups to go through the VPN
# (The OpenVPN server machine may need to NAT
# or bridge the TUN/TAP interface to the internet
# in order for this to work properly).
;push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"

# Certain Windows-specific network settings
# can be pushed to clients, such as DNS
# or WINS server addresses.  CAVEAT:
# http://openvpn.net/faq.html#dhcpcaveats
# The addresses below refer to the public
# DNS servers provided by opendns.com.
;push "dhcp-option DNS 208.67.222.222"
;push "dhcp-option DNS 208.67.220.220"

# Uncomment this directive to allow different
# clients to be able to "see" each other.
# By default, clients will only see the server.
# To force clients to only see the server, you
# will also need to appropriately firewall the
# server's TUN/TAP interface.
;client-to-client

# Uncomment this directive if multiple clients
# might connect with the same certificate/key
# files or common names.  This is recommended
# only for testing purposes.  For production use,
# each client should have its own certificate/key
# pair.
#
# IF YOU HAVE NOT GENERATED INDIVIDUAL
# CERTIFICATE/KEY PAIRS FOR EACH CLIENT,
# EACH HAVING ITS OWN UNIQUE "COMMON NAME",
# UNCOMMENT THIS LINE OUT.
;duplicate-cn

# The keepalive directive causes ping-like
# messages to be sent back and forth over
# the link so that each side knows when
# the other side has gone down.
# Ping every 10 seconds, assume that remote
# peer is down if no ping received during
# a 120 second time period.
keepalive 10 120

# For extra security beyond that provided
# by SSL/TLS, create an "HMAC firewall"
# to help block DoS attacks and UDP port flooding.
#
# Generate with:
#   openvpn --genkey tls-auth ta.key
#
# The server and each client must have
# a copy of this key.
# The second parameter should be '0'
# on the server and '1' on the clients.
;tls-auth ta.key 0 # This file is secret
tls-crypt ta.key

# Select a cryptographic cipher.
# This config item must be copied to
# the client config file as well.
# Note that v2.4 client/server will automatically
# negotiate AES-256-GCM in TLS mode.
# See also the ncp-cipher option in the manpage
;cipher AES-256-CBC
cipher AES-256-GCM
auth SHA256

# Enable compression on the VPN link and push the
# option to the client (v2.4+ only, for earlier
# versions see below)
;compress lz4-v2
;push "compress lz4-v2"

# For compression compatible with older clients use comp-lzo
# If you enable it here, you must also
# enable it in the client config file.
;comp-lzo

# The maximum number of concurrently connected
# clients we want to allow.
;max-clients 100

# It's a good idea to reduce the OpenVPN
# daemon's privileges after initialization.
#
# You can uncomment this out on
# non-Windows systems.
user nobody
group nobody

# The persist options will try to avoid
# accessing certain resources on restart
# that may no longer be accessible because
# of the privilege downgrade.
persist-key
persist-tun

# Output a short status file showing
# current connections, truncated
# and rewritten every minute.
status /var/log/openvpn/openvpn-status.log

# By default, log messages will go to the syslog (or
# on Windows, if running as a service, they will go to
# the "\Program Files\OpenVPN\log" directory).
# Use log or log-append to override this default.
# "log" will truncate the log file on OpenVPN startup,
# while "log-append" will append to it.  Use one
# or the other (but not both).
log         /var/log/openvpn/openvpn.log
;log-append  /var/log/openvpn/openvpn.log

# Set the appropriate level of log
# file verbosity.
#
# 0 is silent, except for fatal errors
# 4 is reasonable for general usage
# 5 and 6 can help to debug connection problems
# 9 is extremely verbose
verb 3

# Silence repeating messages.  At most 20
# sequential messages of the same message
# category will be output to the log.
;mute 20

# Notify the client that when the server restarts so it
# can automatically reconnect.
explicit-exit-notify 1

#mode server
```

Also I noticed that openvpn can't open the file from the path:
`ovpn-server[1257478]: Options error: In [CMD-LINE]:1: Error opening configuration file: /etc/openvpn/server.conf`
But the fact is that I do not have this file along this path. Here is its absolute path:
`/etc/openvpn/server/server.conf`

But if I move the file to a higher directory, I get this error:

```
serv_ivan@964889-cd87180:/etc/openvpn$ sudo systemctl restart  openvpn-server@server.service
Job for openvpn-server@server.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status openvpn-server@server.service" and "journalctl -xeu openvpn-server@server.service" for details.
serv_ivan@964889-cd87180:/etc/openvpn$ sudo tail /var/log/syslog
Aug  2 15:17:17 964889-cd87180 systemd[1]: openvpn@server.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Aug  2 15:17:17 964889-cd87180 systemd[1]: Failed to start OpenVPN connection to server.
Aug  2 15:17:18 964889-cd87180 systemd[1]: openvpn-server@server.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 13907.
Aug  2 15:17:18 964889-cd87180 systemd[1]: Stopped OpenVPN service for server.
Aug  2 15:17:18 964889-cd87180 systemd[1]: Starting OpenVPN service for server...
Aug  2 15:17:18 964889-cd87180 openvpn[1521409]: Options error: In [CMD-LINE]:1: Error opening configuration file: server.conf
Aug  2 15:17:18 964889-cd87180 openvpn[1521409]: Use --help for more information.
Aug  2 15:17:18 964889-cd87180 systemd[1]: openvpn-server@server.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Aug  2 15:17:18 964889-cd87180 systemd[1]: openvpn-server@server.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Aug  2 15:17:18 964889-cd87180 systemd[1]: Failed to start OpenVPN service for server.
serv_ivan@964889-cd87180:/etc/openvpn$
```

I tried to change the path to the working directory, but it didn't work:

```
serv_ivan@964889-cd87180:/etc/openvpn$ cat /usr/lib/systemd/system/openvpn-server@.service
[Unit]
Description=OpenVPN service for %I
After=network-online.target
Wants=network-online.target
Documentation=man:openvpn(8)
Documentation=https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/Openvpn24ManPage
Documentation=https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/HOWTO

[Service]
Type=notify
PrivateTmp=true
#WorkingDirectory=/etc/openvpn/server
WorkingDirectory=/etc/openvpn
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/openvpn --status %t/openvpn-server/status-%i.log --status-version 2 --suppress-timestamps --config %i.conf
CapabilityBoundingSet=CAP_IPC_LOCK CAP_NET_ADMIN CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE CAP_NET_RAW CAP_SETGID CAP_SETUID CAP_SYS_CHROOT CAP_DAC_OVERRIDE CAP_AUDIT_WRITE
LimitNPROC=10
DeviceAllow=/dev/null rw
DeviceAllow=/dev/net/tun rw
ProtectSystem=true
ProtectHome=true
KillMode=process
RestartSec=5s
Restart=on-failure

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
serv_ivan@964889-cd87180:/etc/openvpn$
```

```
serv_ivan@964889-cd87180:/etc/openvpn$ sudo mv server/server.conf ./
serv_ivan@964889-cd87180:/etc/openvpn$ ls
client  server  server.conf  update-resolv-conf
serv_ivan@964889-cd87180:/etc/openvpn$ sudo systemctl restart  openvpn-server@server.service
Warning: The unit file, source configuration file or drop-ins of openvpn-server@server.service changed on disk. Run 'systemctl daemon-reload' to reload units.
Job for openvpn-server@server.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status openvpn-server@server.service" and "journalctl -xeu openvpn-server@server.service" for details.

serv_ivan@964889-cd87180:/etc/openvpn$ sudo systemctl -f enable openvpn-server@server.service
serv_ivan@964889-cd87180:/etc/openvpn$ sudo systemctl start openvpn-server@server.service
Job for openvpn-server@server.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status openvpn-server@server.service" and "journalctl -xeu openvpn-server@server.service" for details.
serv_ivan@964889-cd87180:/etc/openvpn$ sudo systemctl status openvpn-server@server.service
● openvpn-server@server.service - OpenVPN service for server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/openvpn-server@.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2022-08-02 16:14:59 MSK; 3s ago
       Docs: man:openvpn(8)
             https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/Openvpn24ManPage
             https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/HOWTO
    Process: 1534787 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/openvpn --status /run/openvpn-server/status-server.log --status-version 2 --suppress-timestamps --config server.conf (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 1534787 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
        CPU: 14ms

Aug 02 16:14:59 964889-cd87180.tmweb.ru systemd[1]: openvpn-server@server.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Aug 02 16:14:59 964889-cd87180.tmweb.ru systemd[1]: openvpn-server@server.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Aug 02 16:14:59 964889-cd87180.tmweb.ru systemd[1]: Failed to start OpenVPN service for server.
serv_ivan@964889-cd87180:/etc/openvpn$
```

log:

```
serv_ivan@964889-cd87180:/etc/openvpn$ sudo systemctl restart openvpn-server@server.service
Job for openvpn-server@server.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status openvpn-server@server.service" and "journalctl -xeu openvpn-server@server.service" for details.
serv_ivan@964889-cd87180:/etc/openvpn$ sudo tail -n 30 /var/log/syslog
Aug  2 17:53:54 964889-cd87180 systemd[1]: Failed to start OpenVPN service for server.
Aug  2 17:53:54 964889-cd87180 systemd[1]: openvpn@server.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 15243.
Aug  2 17:53:54 964889-cd87180 systemd[1]: Stopped OpenVPN connection to server.
Aug  2 17:53:54 964889-cd87180 systemd[1]: Starting OpenVPN connection to server...
Aug  2 17:53:54 964889-cd87180 systemd[1]: openvpn@server.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Aug  2 17:53:54 964889-cd87180 systemd[1]: openvpn@server.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Aug  2 17:53:54 964889-cd87180 systemd[1]: Failed to start OpenVPN connection to server.
Aug  2 17:53:59 964889-cd87180 systemd[1]: openvpn-server@server.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 15708.
Aug  2 17:53:59 964889-cd87180 systemd[1]: Stopped OpenVPN service for server.
Aug  2 17:53:59 964889-cd87180 systemd[1]: Starting OpenVPN service for server...
Aug  2 17:53:59 964889-cd87180 systemd[1]: openvpn-server@server.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Aug  2 17:53:59 964889-cd87180 systemd[1]: openvpn-server@server.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Aug  2 17:53:59 964889-cd87180 systemd[1]: Failed to start OpenVPN service for server.
Aug  2 17:54:00 964889-cd87180 systemd[1]: openvpn@server.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 15244.
Aug  2 17:54:00 964889-cd87180 systemd[1]: Stopped OpenVPN connection to server.
Aug  2 17:54:00 964889-cd87180 systemd[1]: Starting OpenVPN connection to server...
Aug  2 17:54:00 964889-cd87180 systemd[1]: openvpn@server.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Aug  2 17:54:00 964889-cd87180 systemd[1]: openvpn@server.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Aug  2 17:54:00 964889-cd87180 systemd[1]: Failed to start OpenVPN connection to server.
Aug  2 17:54:01 964889-cd87180 systemd[1]: Stopped OpenVPN service for server.
Aug  2 17:54:01 964889-cd87180 systemd[1]: Starting OpenVPN service for server...
Aug  2 17:54:01 964889-cd87180 systemd[1]: openvpn-server@server.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Aug  2 17:54:01 964889-cd87180 systemd[1]: openvpn-server@server.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Aug  2 17:54:01 964889-cd87180 systemd[1]: Failed to start OpenVPN service for server.
Aug  2 17:54:05 964889-cd87180 systemd[1]: openvpn@server.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 15245.
Aug  2 17:54:05 964889-cd87180 systemd[1]: Stopped OpenVPN connection to server.
Aug  2 17:54:05 964889-cd87180 systemd[1]: Starting OpenVPN connection to server...
Aug  2 17:54:05 964889-cd87180 systemd[1]: openvpn@server.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Aug  2 17:54:05 964889-cd87180 systemd[1]: openvpn@server.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Aug  2 17:54:05 964889-cd87180 systemd[1]: Failed to start OpenVPN connection to server.
serv_ivan@964889-cd87180:/etc/openvpn$
```

Comment: I do not understand what the problem is, everything is in order with access rights, but it still does not start.

Comment: Added configuration file

Answer (score 0):

I found [this solution](https://forums.centos.org/viewtopic.php?t=67967). It's for CentOS, not Ubuntu, but it could work. It says

> Copy config here: /etc/openvpn and change path to files in config to correct.

I'm not sure where you are supposed to "change path", it could be the `WorkingDirectory` in the service file (`/usr/lib/systemd/system/openvpn-server@.service`).

You already tried putting the config file into `/etc/openvpn/`, so maybe you just need to adjust the service file too.

Note: I think it's not enough to copy just the `server.conf`. I think the other files (eg. `ca.crt`) are needed too, because they are referenced by the `server.conf`.

### Is there an error in that guide?

However, this workaround shouldn't be necessary. I created a fresh Ubuntu 22.04 installation in a VM and followed the guide until step 10. I have no separate CA Server, but this shouldn't make a difference for the current problem.

Now guess what? In step 10 the server started without any errors. This doesn't solve your problem. But at least now you know that this guide is probably correct, and the problem is caused by something else.

### Directory and file permissions

You said that everything is in order with access rights. Just to be sure, i'll write down the permission of my working setup:

- The directories `/etc/`, `/etc/openvpn/` and `/etc/openvpn/server/` are owned by `root:root` and chmod'ed to `755`.
- The files in `/etc/openvpn/server/` are owned by `root:root` and chmod'ed to `600`, just the `server.conf` is set to `644`.

Comment: Alas, it didn't help. Output added to the question.

Comment: @АлексШевцов Now when you used this different directory, did you get a different error message too (in syslog or journalctl), or is it the same/similar?

Comment: added log to question.

Comment: @АлексШевцов i added more information.

Comment: I forgot to write in advance that I have root and the main user serv_ivan umask 0077, however, I recursively changed the rights as you described above for these folders and files with similar commands:
find /path/to/dir -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
find /path/to/dir -type f -exec chmod 600 {} \;
And for the server.conf file I set 644

But that didn't help either.

Answer (score 0):

In my case when nginx starts first caused vpn error

if you are using nginx as proxy reverse for your vpn clients, do the following:

```
sudo su
#stop open vpn and nginx
systemctl stop openvpn
systemctl stop nginx

#re-start openvpn first 
systemctl start openvpn
systemctl status openvpn


#finally restart your nginx service 
systemctl start nginx
systemctl status nginx
```